# Existence of a fixed point of a continuous linear operator T in a convex compact subset K of a normed linear space E

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, functional-analysis

Let K be a convex compact set which is non empty in a normed space E, and let T be a continuous linear map from E into itself, which maps $K$ into itself. I want to show that T has a fixed point in K. I tried using the sequence $u_0 \in K; u_n= \frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^nT^k(a) $  to get the recurrence relation $u_n = \frac{a}{n+1} + \frac{n}{n+1}T(u_{n-1})$. I know that since K is compact $u_n$ has a limit point b. I am guessing that b is the fixed point. But I am having a little difficulty show that. Now, if b were the limit of the sequence I can easily show that it is the fixed point using the recurrence relation, but that is not so. I think this might have something to do with the fact that K is convex.

Comment: This is Schauder's Fixed Point Theorem. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schauder_fixed-point_theorem

Comment: The fact that $K$ is convex is used to **define** $u_n$ and have it be well-defined.